# Changing resolution does change camera

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

On Blender 2.9 when I change the output resolution also the camera does change, does anyone know why? How to fix it?

I had the same scene on Blender 2.8 and it didn’t had this issue.

Here the image from 2 different sizes of rendering on Blender 2.9

[image]

I’ve already tried to re-create the camera and to press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> with no results.
Also in the “View Port” the camera looks always right.

---

Here the first render with showed edges:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The first image on the top is complete as I showed it

Comment: The field of view does not change when you change the number of pixels rendered (unless you are rendering with a different aspect ratio). You are using a render region, that might be the issue. Press Ctrl+ Alt+ B to clear it.

Comment: Are you using any nodes in the compositor?

Comment: I already tried without render region but the result is the same.. There is almost nothing in the compositor. Just a thing about Image and Alpha

Comment: Could it be because I use a modified version? It's the E-Cycles version

Comment: Hello :). Can't reproduce the issue. Isn't it just zoomed-in? Try *View > Frame All Fit* (Shift + Home) to see if the results are the same.

Comment: Well, Is not a problem of the image fitting on the render box.. I checked already.